# C# - Cannot deserialize the current JSON array

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have this code:

```
string json2 = vc.Request(model.uri + "?fields=uri,transcode.status", "GET");
var deserial = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(json2);
var transcode = deserial["transcode"];
var serial = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(transcode);
var deserial2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(serial);
var upstatus = deserial2["status"].ToString();
```

The json I get from the server is:

```
{
    "uri": "/videos/262240241",
    "transcode": {
        "status": "in_progress"
    }
}
```

When running it on VS2017, it works.

But on VS2010 I get the following error:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]'
>   because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to
>   deserialize correctly.
>       To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a
>   type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList)
>   like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array.
>   JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
>   deserialize from a JSON array.
>       Path '', line 1, position 1.

I am using Newtonsoft.Json.

Any idea?

Comment: The answer is easy. please use visual studio json special past to create the unserialise object.

Comment: I asked a question further down, but: Are the framework versions you're using the same between the VS2017 and VS2010 project? Is the version of JSON.Net the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best answer was deleted for some reason, so i'll post it:

```
var deserial = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json2);
string upstatus = string.Empty;
upstatus = deserial.transcode.status.ToString();
```

Answer (score 3):

Your received json data is not a `Dictionary<string, object>`, it is a object

```
public class Transcode
{
    public string status { get; set; }
}

public class VModel
{
    public string uri { get; set; }
    public Transcode transcode { get; set; }
}
```

You can use this object:

```
var deserial = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VModel>(json2);
```

instead of:

```
var deserial = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(json2);
```

Comment: The json provided is also a valid Dictionary<string, object>

Comment: @AaYy Are the framework versions you're using the same between the VS2017 and VS2010 project? Is the version of JSON.Net the same?

Answer (score 2):

If your model is not well defined or it is dynamic, then use:

```
var deserial = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json2);
```

or you can try to use:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(json2);
```